# Hibernate Envers delete mode

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-envers

I use hibernate-envers 4.1.8.Final

my envers config :
    org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true

I expect that when I delete a record in base Table, 
new record will insert in table_aud with same column and the same data.
but no! the data not inserted in table_aud offcource except revtype and rev

in other words the above config does not work correctly!
    Can Any one help me?

Comment: Could you include how you're passing this property into Hibernate?  Is it from a hibernate.properties file or via some spring-configuration?

Comment: in appContext-hibernate.xml:

<property> 

    <props>
       <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete">true</prop>
    </props>

</property>

Comment: If you create a hibernate.properties file in the root of your classpath with the property configuration and retry your scenario does it work?

Comment: yes,I create it in root of my classpath but  so it does not work!

Comment: How are you deleting the data?

Comment: By formal delete,with hibernate Hql!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, the problem is the fact you're using HQL in order to delete the entity reference rather than using the two removal methods specified on the EntityManager / Session:

- `session.delete(Object)`
- `entityManager.remove(Object)`

When using JPQL or HQL statements, Hibernate does not raise specific events and therefore the integrations that listen for those events are not notified.  In this case, a `post-delete` event isn't raised and so that is why you never see a `REVTYPE` row being added for a `RevisionType.DEL` entry.

Using either of the two mentioned methods above will resolve your problem.

The driving factor here is that a HQL / JPQL statement can act as a bulk operation much like JPA's intent with `CriteriaDelete` and `CriteriaUpdate`.  These are meant to apply a DML operation potentially at bulk to a database object without the persistence provider necessarily having to *load* the entity state into the persistence context.

Think about the use case you're attempting.  Imagine that your entity has not been loaded from the database and you're simply calling `DELETE FROM YourEntity WHERE id = :id`.  No entity state is loaded in this case, so if the event were to be fired, the only pertinent information known is:

- Entity Type
- Some attribute named `id` with a given value specified by `:id`.

In this case the attribute is the primary key perhaps, but that could have easily been any random attribute on that entity class, so really there is no effective way to audit such a use case without initializing the persistence context with the entity state first.  That would be a wasteful operation particularly for `DELETE` operations if the operation would have been for a bulk number of rows.

Hope that offers some insight as to *why* you see what you do.